# How to find Google Workspace Developer Add-Ons

Tags: google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I've previously created an published an add on for Google Sheets I was waiting for it to be approved.

I want to check the status but cannot find the screen to do that.

Please help

Comment: Did you try the solution given by Gabriel? Were you able to check on the status?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the status of the Add on and you have already submitted the Add on for verification you can follow the steps in [`How to publish an App`](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish). You just need to have access to the account that you used to submit the App and then go to [`console.cloud.google.com`](https://console.cloud.google.com/). Once there you just need to follow the steps from the documentation above and you should find the screen that displays the status of your app.